# How to create popup window like sharepoint

Tags: modal-dialog, popup

When you select an item, a popup window appears with its data, inside the window. How can I do that?  It would be preferable to use JavaScript functions from SharePoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SharePoint dialog API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff410058(v=office.14).aspx) for displaying Popup's.

Below is a utility function you can use. Pass the page URL you want to display as a popup

```
function ShowDialog(url) {
    var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
    options.url = url;
    options.height = 300;
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}
```

Comment: SP.UI.ModalDialog is not shown - I use firebug. I only have:

Comment: Check file `SP.UI.Dialog.js` is loaded.